# Azure Mobile App service exception "The item does not exist" while InsertAsync

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-mobile-services

I have interested situation. I have class and the table on Azure:

```
public class InmeItem
{
      public string Id { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "heartrate")]
      public string Heartrate { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pulsewave")]
      public string Pulsewave { get; set; }
}
```

I have follow code to insert new item to the table:

```
public static async Task InsertInmeItem(InmeItem inmeitem)
{
     try
     {
         await App.MobileService.GetTable<InmeItem>().InsertAsync(inmeitem);
     }

     catch (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
     {
           Debug.WriteLine("This is f***** situation which post data but generate exception: " + ex.ToString());
     }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           Debug.WriteLine(ex);
     }
}
```

But I have some interested situation - running throw exception "The item does not exist" but data was inserted in the table on Azure without any exceptions

Exception info:

```
This is f***** situation which post data  but generate exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The item does not exist
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<>c__DisplayClass14.<<InsertAsync>b__13>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<TransformHttpException>d__4d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<InsertAsync>d__1a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<TransformHttpException>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<InsertAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<InsertAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at InmeTesting.Models.Backoffice.<InsertInmeItem>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are returning the correct results from the insert function, i.e. it expects you to return the inserted item. You don't necessarily need to return the inserted item, but you must return something to render to the client, or the framework will return a 404 instead with a message "The item does not exist".

The first example succeeds because context.execute returns the inserted item. In the second example, the item is clearly not being returned from the block of code in the .then() call.

Answer (score 0):

I found reason.

For this exeption may be 2 reasons

1. Not equal name of the of class for database and name of the table on cloud (but classes are equal)
2. Theese exception also throw if on backend (on my case this is Node JS) in `table.insert(function (context) {...});` there is `then()` in `return context.execute();`

For example this code

```
table.insert(function (context) {
   //context.item.userId = context.user.id;

   //Retranslate data to inme server
   retranslateToInme(context.item.heartrate, context.item.pulsewave);

   return context.execute();
});
```

do not throw a exception. But:

```
table.insert(function (context) {
   //context.item.userId = context.user.id;

   //Retranslate data to inme server
   retranslateToInme(context.item.heartrate, context.item.pulsewave);

   return context.execute().then(...);
});
```

will throw the exception